# LightDM is missing Gnome Shell icon

Tags: gnome, icons, lightdm, 14.04

the Icon of Gnome shell is missing from lightDM.. I had to manually add Gnome Shell to lightDM because it didn't install properly on my machine. now I don't now how to add the Icon to lightDM.

Im on Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In 14.04 the `gnome-session` package was split so that there is also an `ubuntu-session` package. In a standard Ubuntu 14.04 install, the `gnome-session` part won't be installed by default, so if you only installed `gnome-shell` you won't get the `/usr/share/xsessions/gnome.desktop` xsession file which is what LightDM reads to add the session. So the fix is:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-session
```

In previous versions both the Unity and gnome-shell xsession files were in the same package and installed by default so you only needed to install `gnome-shell`.

Comment: thanks you so much. that solved everything i had problems with in one go.